# How to put iOS App in US App Store using Indian details

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am resident of India and have developed an iPhone App which is mainly targeted for users in US. I tried to clear my doubts using the documentation given by Apple but I am still confused.

Can someone please clarify that : If I buy a Standard Developer License from Apple using Indian Billing Address, and publish the App, will it be visible to ONLY Indian users or world-wide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit an application through iTunes Connect, you can select which countries it is available in.  It defaults to world-wide.  You aren't restricted to your own country.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that means it does not matter on where I am, it just matters where all i want to show my app. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No, not only india but all the countries and regions you defined in iTunes Connect.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henrik, I think i can go ahead and buy the license then.